# How do I clear particular range of cells in VSTO excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have 2 questions.

1. I want to clear  a range of cells in Excel VSTO apps.
2. When the user opens the Excel for the first time, I want to populate a particular cell with the user's name and address. After that I want it to be saved in the excel and it should not be populated if the user opens again. How do I accomplish this task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question 1:

```
private void ClearRange(string rangeAddress)
{
    var rng = worksheet.get_Range(rangeAddress, Type.Missing);
    rng.Clear();
}
```

For question 2: You're going to need to implement an event handler. Unfortunately there is no event handler for "open Excel for the first time". So you'll need to figure out a programmatic solution for keeping track of what the "first time" is, and saving that information somehow. I'd recommend grabbing a good book on VSTO (here's [my personal recommendation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321533216)).

That being said, I think you're going to have to work with `Application.WorkbookOpen`.

In the WorkbookOpen event handler, you should put the code to set the user's name and address to their respective cells. You can also choose to save a `CustomProperty` to mark the fact that you've populated these fields at this time.